# What is KIE in SAP Hybris promotion setup?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, kie, commerce

I am looking for the explanation of KIE term being used thoroughly while setting up Hybris Promotions.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Commerce's Promotion Engine is based on an underlying technology called the Drools rule engine. Drools is a JBoss Community open source project, and sits under a grouping of project that share some base-level logic. This grouping is called 'Knowledge is Everything' ... abbreviated as KIE.  See also: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.59.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html